# How to use quickly with c++

Tags: application-development, quickly, c++

I wanted to know that how can i create application using c++ with quickly.
Recently i wanted to use pyside with it so i deleted all the files in the main folder expect **init**.py
And it works
I wanted to know i paste all my files there that i have worked with qt creator c++ will it work.
If not tell me other ways.
I seriously want to use c++ as it is more powerful and easy(at least for me) then python

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, currently quickly don't have any stable templates for c++ . So you should create and package apps manually